# addSearchFilter fails if being used in SOAP call

Tags: soap, catalogsearch, ce-1.6.2.0

I have this code in a SOAP call:

```
private function doSearchResults($terms)
{
    try {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addSearchFilter($terms);
        return $collection->getSelect();
        $collection = $collection
            ->setStore(1)
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    //$collection->load();
    //return $collection;
}
```

Notice that, to narrow the problem, I put a `return` sentence in the middle.

If I call this inside a custom controller, it works. If I call this inside a SOAP call, it returns the following error message:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`
 INNER JOIN' at line 1
```

**edit**: How do I know that the failing method is that? Because the former code I tested was:

```
private function doSearchResults($terms)
{
    try {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $collection->getSelect();
        $collection = $collection
            ->addSearchFilter($terms)
            ->setStore(1)
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    //$collection->load();
    //return $collection;
}
```

And it worked : I debugged the select object. The text in "terms" is always set.

**My question is**: **why** does it work in a **controller** but not in **soap**?

My SOAP user has access to every resource.